# Clear console.time timer in node

Tags: javascript, node.js

In Nodejs, is there a way to clear a timer created by `console.time` without calling `console.timeEnd`?

For example, consider the following:

```
console.time("Timer for an asynchronous operation that may fail");

this.get(somethingToGet, function(err, value){
    if(!err && value != undefined){
        console.timeEnd("Timer for an asynchronous operation that may fail");
    } else {
        // clear the timer without printing to the console
    }
});
```

If there is no error I want to print the timer and label to the console, but if there is an error I want to clear it, so it doesn't run forever, without printing anything to the console.

Comment: I don't believe there's any way to kill a timer without printing  https://github.com/DeveloperToolsWG/console-object/blob/master/api.md#timing reference that among other things.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to worry about that as there's nothing "running" about the timer.  Calling `console.time` just records a start time for the label.  See [source](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/a35b32ec1e07cc25ca67b5718b5332b5a3bedad6/lib/internal/console/constructor.js#L380).

If you look at the `timeEnd` implementation below it, you'll see that calling that doesn't even clear the entry to allow you to call `timeEnd` multiple times for the same label at different times.

Comment: Oh gotcha, thanks!  So if I later tried the same operation again and used the same label, it would just overwrite the old start time?

Comment: Right, it only stores one timestamp per label.

Comment: It looks like this does now clear itself out of the `_times` map